# Некорректное отображение комментария на китайском VC 2015

Tags: visual-studio

В VC2015 комментарии отображаются неправильно.

```
//±ШРлУЕПИ¶ЁТеЕдЦГОДјюЧЦ·ыґ®
```

Как исправить? И еще можно как-нибудь перевести с китайского на английский прямо в VC?

Comment: А какой у вас язык операционки? Вам нужно было сохранить файлы в Unicode (utf-8 или utf-16).

Comment: Visual Studio, конечно, умеет очень многое, но не думаю, что там есть встроенная функциональность перевода с одного (человеческого) языка на другой.

Comment: Язык русский. Я скачал готовые исходники. Text reader на  android отобразил с помощью кодировки euc-kr

Comment: А, если у вас есть оригинал исходников, попробуйте загрузить в их кодировке и сконвертировать таки в utf-8.